# Unhalted error by system call

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I am trying to call 'cls' command using the following:

```
Process.Start("cls");
```

When i execute this line the program halts. If I switch 'cls', lets say to 'notepad' the progam works properly. Why is that?

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad is an actual exe; cls is a command to the interpreter, not an exe. <s>You can probably "fix" it by toggling use-shell-invoke</s>, but either way, it won't help because it isn't clearing *your* console window, but the console window of the newly spawned process.

I suspect you want:

```
Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Oh dear... Clear() calls cls ... Why they hide everything with just another implementation? My origin is ANSI C, which everyhting is more clear and every implementation has its reason ... Marc thanks a bunch for clearing things out.

Comment: @Sunscreen - it isn't so much that "Clear() calls cls"; more that both serve the same purpose: they clear the console. Neither is an exe, also.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because `cls` is not a process that can be started (in contrast to notepad), but a command of the command prompt. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to execute a program called `cls`. Is there such a program? (If you're thinking of the `cls` command you have in a command window, that isn't a separate program, it's a command implemented inside the `cmd` program.)